# Routes error with django models migrations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a file named routes.py where I have that

```
router.register('orders', OrderViewSet, 'order')
```

If I comment that I don't have problems with the migrations, but in production, and my boss say I cannot comment that every time that I want to migrate.

In te serializer.py I have this:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    buyer_obj = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    #items = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'buyer', 'items', 'store', 'buyer_obj',
            'browser_ip', 'currency', 'enabled',
            'financial_status', 'gateway', 'total_amount')
```

The Error is the next:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054), "Unkown column 'orders_order.currency' in 'field list'")
```

Please exist another form to migrate that?
Thank you.

Comment: Does your `Order` model have a `currency` field inside it?

Comment: Yes, but it is a new currency and when I make makemigrations this problem appear

Comment: can you show the code of your Order model?